# How can I implement cometchat in Codeigniter? to show online user or etc

Tags: php, codeigniter

I implemented comet chat with codeigniter, it's working almost as expected but I still have some problems and need to rectify soon. Problem listed below.

1. When I logged in with 2-3 users in different browsers, it randomly
   change their status "Offline" and "Online", don't know why? however
   all the users are online.
2. Sometimes when I logged in with the site, cometchat bar at bottom
   shows only the text "Offline" means "0 online users" and once I
   clicked on the cometchat bar then it start displaying the actual
   status and count of the users.

Comment: Hi, without showing us some code / narrowing the question down to something specific we can hardly help you.

Comment: This one http://www.cometchat.com/codeigniter-chat ?

Comment: Try to increaste ONLINE_TIMEOUT http://www.cometchat.com/answers/how-do-i-synchronize-the-status-of-users-on-my-site-as-per-their-cometchats-status/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you have a look at the following:

http://support.cometchat.com/documentation/php/installing-cometchat/ready-integrations/codeigniter/

If you want to increase the length of time before they timeout you can edit:

ONLINE_TIMEOUT in cometchat/config.php file, which stores default online time out value. This value is by default set to 60

If you still face issues, I suggest you contact them at http://www.cometchat.com/contact

I've used CometChat on a number of my sites without any issues. So you may want to check your configuration again.